# Trying to create a new PowerBi custom visual gives style error

Tags: typescript, powerbi

I'm trying to create a new Powerbi custom visual with `powerbi-visuals-tools@2.5.0`. I create a new custom visual with `pbiviz new <name>` and installing dependencies with `npm i`, but everytime i try to `pbiviz start` I get the same error.

```
info   Building visual...
error  LESS  style/visual.less :  The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
```

The content of `style/visual.less`:

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    em {
        background: yellow;
        padding: 5px;
        
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hey man, I'm having the EXACT same problem. I'm trying to downgrade my node version, see if it helps. Let me know if you figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the latest version of `powerbi-visuals-tools`. `2.5.0` is really old one.
I've just tested on `3.1.15`, it works fine.

Comment: That was what I actually did at that moment. I forgot about this question tho.